# are there independence results in differential geometry/differential topology?

Tags: differential-geometry, logic, set-theory, differential-topology

[wikipedia has a list of some statements known to be independent of ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_statements_independent_of_ZFC), but there are no examples in differential geometry/differential topology; does anyone know if there is one?

or if maybe there's a way of showing something along the lines of "smooth manifolds are very well-behaved, so there can't be any"

Comment: I do not understand why this question is closed. It seems that the question is well-posed, and how can we add more details to this question?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Are Perfectly Normal Manifolds Metrisable?](https://www.springerprofessional.de/en/are-perfectly-normal-manifolds-metrisable/4862378), the question whether every perfectly normal manifold is metrisable, is independent of ZFC.

Comment: chapter 7 of gauld about smoothness contains no idependence results, and it seems to play no role in this chapter 6 [neither in rudin and zenor (1976)], although it does appear in the referenced koslowski and zenor (1976)

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis The essential part is already in the answer, namely the quote of a statement that is independent of ZFC...